# synchronization of read parallel , write one at a time

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-safety

I have a object obj that is read by many threads frequently , but updated by only one thread periodically.The update happens after long some interval (say 10 minutes).

The data is less transnational.Meaning if  read threads gets stale data(old) for some time then its perfectly ok.

Now i thought of using following approach for synchronization:

```
final Object lock = new Object();
private MyObject obj = new MyObject(); //this is the data

public String getDataFieldName(){
 synchronized(lock){
   return this.obj.name;
 }
}


/*the following code is wrong right?As its just synchronizes the code for getting reference.But after getting reference read thread R1 may try to get data while write Thread is modifying data.Will that give exception?How to solve this? */
public String getData(){
 synchronized(lock){
   return this.obj;
 }
}

//only one thread can update.But how multipe threads can read at once?
public updateData(args ) {
  synchronized(lock){
    //do update
 }

}
```

My questions are as follows:

1. I dont want only one thread to read the data.Reads should be parallel.
2. How can i synchronize read  and write ?If write thread is updating  and read thread is reading i dont what to get some exception.It is ok if read gets some old data
   3)If read thread is reading while write thread is updating , will i get exception?Will there be any problem?

Comment: You should look into [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html)

Comment: @Thomas, you should look into posting that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any synchronization in this scenario. All you have to do is the following:

- Make sure `MyObject` is [immutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html), meaning that you never change any values in your object Instead you construct a new `MyData` object everytime you change it. This prevents anyone from seeing a half-changed object.
- Declare obj as [volatile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html), to make sure all threads see the updated value everytime.

You will never get an exception because of concurrent reads and writes if you follow these steps.

Comment: +1, but worth mentioning that this is only feasible as long as it's not expensive to construct.  It may be a large HashMap cache for example.

Comment: Agreed, but since he is only constructing a new object every 10 minutes it would have to be a really really big object for that to be a problem.

Comment: @SimonC ,@Keppil : The actual object is constructed  by loading values from DB and its expensive.

Comment: @Keppil even if i construct new object everytime , i need to update the reference of the object in this class .Also i will ned to synchronized getData method as i have shown in code above right?If i synchronize getData then only one thread will be able to get the reference at a time , right?

Comment: @user978939: The reference update is an atomic operation, so that's ok. You won't need any synchronization at all, neither in getData() nor in setData(). And also, constructing an expensive object once every 10 minutes is most probably fine.

Comment: @Keppil :But what if when read thread is getting a reference when write thread is updating reference?

Comment: @user978939: Then two things can happen. Either the write happens first, and the reading Thread gets the new data, or the read happens first and the reading Thread will use the old data. They can't happen at the same time, since reads and writes of volatile variables are atomic.

Comment: @Keppil : but about noon valatine variables?

Comment: @user978939: If you follow the `volatile` link above, it says that `Reads and writes are atomic for reference variables and for most primitive variables (all types except long and double).`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use volatile keyword, that will not take the lock, unlike synchronization does, and will provide multiple access, reflecting the updates of one thread to the another..
2. But then its always better to have some sort of synchronization, as volatile will not ensure to prevent the Race Condition on the data. So if you dont want to use synchronization, then better go with Immutable object

**Eg:**

```
import java.util.Date;

/**
* Planet is an immutable class, since there is no way to change
* its state after construction.
*/
public final class Planet {


 //Final primitive data is always immutable.

  private final double fMass;

  private final String fName;

  private final Date fDateOfDiscovery;

  public Planet (double aMass, String aName, Date aDateOfDiscovery) {
     fMass = aMass;
     fName = aName;
     //make a private copy of aDateOfDiscovery
     //this is the only way to keep the fDateOfDiscovery
     //field private, and shields this class from any changes that 
     //the caller may make to the original aDateOfDiscovery object
     fDateOfDiscovery = new Date(aDateOfDiscovery.getTime());
  }


  public double getMass() {
    return fMass;
  }


  public String getName() {
    return fName;
  }




  public Date getDateOfDiscovery() {
    return new Date(fDateOfDiscovery.getTime());
  }


}
```